# Function removing the first instance of a value using only lambda, filter, map, and reduce

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am trying to create a function that will take a tuple and remove the first instance of a value. For example:
`print(Remove((0, 1, 2, 1, 3), 1))`
should return `(0, 2, 1, 3)`.

I am using functional programming and not using any predefined functions. I'm allowed to use only `lambda`, `filter`, `map`, and `reduce` but nothing else. I  can't use `list.remove` or for-loops. 
I assume a filter function will work best for this. I have figured out that the following function will work to remove all instances of the value `E`. I now need to know how to just remove the first instance of `E`.

```
def Remove(T,E):
   return tuple(filter(lambda x: x!=E, T))
```

Comment: This would be possible in languages like haskell or prolog which allow multiple definitions of a single function. python lambda functions don't allow the use of local variables.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with simple recursion

1. If the input tuple, `t`, is empty, return the empty result
2. (inductive) Otherwise `t` is *not* empty - `t` has *at least one* element. If the first element of `t` matches the element to remove, `x`, return the tail of the tuple
3. (inductive) Otherwise, `t` is *not* empty and the first element of `t` does *not* match the element to remove, `x`. Create a new tuple with the first element of `t` and the recursive result

Numbered comments below correspond to the explanation above -

```
def remove(t, x):
  if not t:       # 1
    return ()
  elif t[0] == x: # 2
    return t[1::]
  else:           # 3
    return (t[0], *remove(t[1::], x))

print(remove((0, 1, 2, 1, 3), 1))
# (0, 2, 1, 3)
```

Python has an eccentric syntax for interacting with elements of collections. By defining a few helper functions, we can establish a robust and consistent way of writing this kind of program -

```
def is_empty(x):
  return not x

def head(x):
  if is_empty(x)
    raise RuntimeError("head called on empty input")
  else:
    return x[0]

def tail(x):
  if is_empty(x)
    raise RuntimeError("tail called on empty input")
  else:
    return x[1::]

def remove(t, x):
  if is_empty(x):
    return ()
  elif head(t) == x:
    return tail(t)
  else:
    return (head(t), *remove(tail(t), x))

print(remove((0, 1, 2, 1, 3), 1))
# (0, 2, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
numbers = (2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 6)
e = 3  # element to remove
nums_removed = tuple(
    filter(
        lambda x, found=[False, True]: not (not found[0] and x == e and found.reverse() is None),
        numbers
    )
)
print(nums_removed)
```

Output:

```
(2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 6)
```

However, I can't understand why someone would want to write code so bad. It's like going from USA to USA via India.

The point is to use functional programming when it produces a simpler and more beautiful code and use anything else that is already available to make life easier.

I ended up writing a `lambda` function which I myself don't really understand completely, but it works. I kept trying different approaches to see what works because I was bored. You can't have local variables inside lambda functions, so I used a **mutable default argument `found`** to save function state. I posted it as an answer as soon as it worked.

If someone wants to add an explanation to my answer, feel free to edit it.